# MongoDB: get _id of document having given value and use it in query

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections:

```
Users:  
{
_id:12345647890,
email:"aaa@gmail.com"  
}  

Documents:
{
_id:0987654321,
owner:1234567890,
text:"aaa"}
{
_id:0987654322,
owner:1234567890,
text:"bbb"}
```

I want to find all documents belonging to person with `aaa@gmail.com` email.

I know I can first find `_id` of a person in `Users` collection using given email and then find all documents from `Documents`, but probably there is a way to achieve it in one query, something like:

```
Documents.find({owner is equal _id taken from Users where Users.email is equal aaa@gmail.com})
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-single-equality) aggregation pipeline to effect a join between your referenced documents, and combine that with a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline to filter the results.

```
db.Users.aggregate([
  { $match: { email: { $eq: 'searchterm' }}},
  { $lookup:
        {
          from: "documents",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "owner",
          as: "user_documents"
         }
  }
])
```

The official documentation around Mongodb aggregations can be a little sparse on examples, but there are plenty of blogs out there with [workable code](https://engineering.universe.com/mongo-aggregations-in-5-minutes-b8e1d9c274bb).
Another good resource for code snippets and practical examples will be the unit tests for whatever driver you're using (e.g. c#, java etc).

I should also mention two related points:

- Just running two queries is often a simple and viable alternative, which you shouldnt discount automatically - provided you dont have enormous collections. In many cases the performance difference may be negligible.
- With whichever approach you choose, make sure you are indexing your foreign key reference!

Comment: Is it possible to use `find` instead of `aggregate`? At my task all I can do is to create `find` query and pass to as a result further.

Comment: Not in a single operation. But if for whatever reason you can only use `$find` then you can just run two consecutive queries to get the same result. As mentioned above, this is normally still quite performant provided you have the correct indexes set up.